# index.js:1375 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I noticed this error after I added a  (react-route-dom) if the user is already authenticated.
I can't figure out why I'm having this error.
I found some similar question, and the answer always about `'undefined'` state.. but I think this is not the case.

This is my code:

```
function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, dispatch] = useUserStore();

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    remember: false
  });

  const { email, password, remember } = formData;

  const handleChange = e =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim() });

  const submitForm = async form => {
    form.preventDefault();

    login(email, password, remember, dispatch);
  };

  if (state.auth.isAuthenticated) return <Redirect to="/setting" />;

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={form => submitForm(form)}>
          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address or Username"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
            autoFocus
          />

          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />

         ...
```